# Does the jOOQ 3.15.1 new ad-hoc conversion API work in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, jooq

I am attempting to translate the worked-example from [jOOQ 3.15's New Multiset Operator Will Change How You Think About SQL](https://blog.jooq.org/jooq-3-15s-new-multiset-operator-will-change-how-you-think-about-sql/) into Kotlin, but am having some type-inference issues preventing me from compiling.

Here it is so far:

- using the `sakila` schema
- generating Kotlin from the jOOQ code generation step
- adapting Java's `CompletionStage` future to Kotlin co-routines with the `async()` [extension method](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8/src/future/Future.kt) from `kotlinx.coroutines.jdk-8`

```kotlin
    data class Actor(val firstName: String?, val lastName: String?)
    data class Film(val title: String?, val actors: List<Actor>, val 
    categories: List<String>)

    ...

    val future = dsl.select(
        FILM.TITLE,
        multiset(
            select(
                FILM_ACTOR.actor().FIRST_NAME,
                FILM_ACTOR.actor().LAST_NAME
            )
                .from(FILM_ACTOR)
                .where(FILM_ACTOR.FILM_ID.eq(FILM.FILM_ID))
        ).`as`("actors").convertFrom { it.map( mapping(::Actor) ) }, // <--[1]
        multiset(
            select(FILM_CATEGORY.category().NAME)
                .from(FILM_CATEGORY)
                .where(FILM_CATEGORY.FILM_ID.eq(FILM.FILM_ID))
        ).`as`("films").convertFrom { it.map { r -> r.getValue(0) } }
    )
        .from(FILM)
        .orderBy(FILM.TITLE)
        .fetchAsync()

    val result = future.await().map( mapping(::Film) ) // <--[2]
```

Problems I'm having are noted at [1] and [2] in the code.

**At [1], it comes down to Kotlin vs Java when getting the constructor reference:**

```
Type mismatch.
Required:  ((String?, String?) → Actor!)!
Found:     KFunction2<String, String, Actor>
```

... which is close, but no cigar.  There is probably a simple way to adapt it that I'm missing (other than manually invoking the constructor).

**At [2], Kotlin can't decide which overload of `mapping(...)` to select.**

It is currently opaque to me why the issue is different in each case.

*Can I please get some guidance whether the `mapping(/*constructor reference*/): RecordManager<R,U>` is expected to work with Kotlin in jOOQ 3.15.1?* and if not, what I might reasonably do to work around it?

Comment: I just have to say, this little interop edge-case aside, I'm totally in awe of the MULTISET feature.  Using jOOQ is like driving a rocket!

Comment: Regarding the `await()` adding complexity to the above, I moved that discussion to [SO: Does jOOQ play nicely with kotlin coroutines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68915965/does-jooq-play-nicely-with-kotlin-coroutines/68915966#68915966)

Answer (score 3):

Regarding problem [1], it's sometimes not an option to make the attributes nullable: your whole application will then be contaminated by this nullable attribute. Even though the column might be specified as NOT NULL in the database, jOOQ (3.15.1) currently doesn't provide non-null record fields (since they are not guaranteed to be non-null in e.g. outer joins).

With non-nullable attributes, the simplest solution I've found so far is this construct:

```kotlin
    multiset(
        select(
            FILM_ACTOR.actor().FIRST_NAME,
            FILM_ACTOR.actor().LAST_NAME
        )
    .from(FILM_ACTOR)
    .where(FILM_ACTOR.FILM_ID.eq(FILM.FILM_ID))
    ).`as`("actors").convertFrom(List::class.java) { it.map { s -> Actor(s.value1()!!, s.value2()!!) } },
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful.  Only a few tens of characters more to get the type you want, and if you're doing it a lot, you can write a `(Record2<X?,Y?>) -> Z` function and reuse it.

Answer (score 2):

A: Yes it does!

This is the most straightforward Kotlin equivalent of the final worked example at [jOOQ 3.15's New Multiset Operator Will Change How You Think About SQL](https://blog.jooq.org/jooq-3-15s-new-multiset-operator-will-change-how-you-think-about-sql/) without adding any complexity with `fetchAsync()`.

The declared properties of the data classes must all be nullable types.

```
data class Actor(val firstName: String?, val lastName: String?)
data class Film(val title: String?, val actors: List<Actor>?, val categories: List<String>?)
```

and then

```
    val result = dsl.select(
            FILM.TITLE,
            multiset(
                select(
                    FILM_ACTOR.actor().FIRST_NAME,
                    FILM_ACTOR.actor().LAST_NAME
                )
                    .from(FILM_ACTOR)
                    .where(FILM_ACTOR.FILM_ID.eq(FILM.FILM_ID))
            ).`as`("actors").convertFrom { it?.map( mapping(::Actor) ) },
            multiset(
                select(FILM_CATEGORY.category().NAME)
                    .from(FILM_CATEGORY)
                    .where(FILM_CATEGORY.FILM_ID.eq(FILM.FILM_ID))
            ).`as`("films").convertFrom { it?.map { r -> r.getValue1() } }
        )
            .from(FILM)
            .orderBy(FILM.TITLE)
            .fetch( mapping(::Film) )
```

## Gotchas

The gotchas I had included:

- not making all properties of my data/record classes use nullable types
- accidentally used `Record1#getValue()` instead of `Record1#getValue1()` to map the name of the film, and therefore had an `Any!` instead of a `String!`
- my `data class Film(...)` not being used because IDEA had imported the same-named class that jOOQ generates instead of using mine

In all of the above cases, the problems manifest as 'wrong type inference` issues with bewildering presentations.

I also had:

- an NPE in the `convertFrom{...}` blocks where depending on the data in the table, it was possible that `it` was null!  (In an unmodified Sakila database, I had problems with `author`)
- trouble invoking `Record#map(RecordMapper)` ... sometimes with `mapping(::MyClass)` to get a `RecordMapper` (in which case, `map`**`()`** is the right invocation style) and sometimes with a lambda with signature `R -> T` (in which case `map`**`{}`**) is the right invocation style.  Using the latter style, but supplying a `RecordMapper` via `mapping()` gives you the wrong type later on!  eg.

```
convertFrom { it?.map( mapping(::Actor) } // <- gives List<Actor> in the object graph's type after fetch()
```

vs

```
convertFrom { it?.map { mapping(::Actor) } // <- gives List<RecordMapper<Record3<...etc...>,Actor>> in the object's graph type after fetch()
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Your error `[1]`

Are you sure you made your attributes in the data class nullable in the test? The error message is:

> ```
> Type mismatch.
> Required:  ((String?, String?) → Actor!)!
> Found:     KFunction2<String, String, Actor>
> ```

The latter should be `KFunction2<String?, String?, Actor>` instead.

#### Your error `[2]`

Not sure what the kotlinx-coroutines library does here, but if you use JDK `CompletionStage` API, this also works for me (with the correct nullability applied):

```kotlin
.fetchAsync().thenApply { mapping(::Film) }
```

Perhaps that, too, is a side-effect of wrong nullability being applied

Comment: You were right about #1.  My bad - I had sorted it when adding my answer with my own `mapping()` functions, and  THEN added the lines to the question.   #2 needed 2 x fixes: a) IDEA had imported the symbol `Film` from the table-class that jOOQ had generated, and wasn't even using my `data class Film(...)`, and b) I had to change `r -> r.getValue(0)` to `r -> r.getValue(0) as String`.  I'll amend my answer to write this up.

Comment: @DavidBullock Ah yes, the `getValue(int)` method doen't know the type of the column. Thanks for documenting your findings with your own answer! I think the question is still very useful for future visitors, as they might run into similar typing problems, especially the nullability one.