# Does jOOQ play nicely with Kotlin coroutines?

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, jooq, nonblocking

**[Kotlin coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-guide.html)** and 'suspending functions' make it easy for the programmer to await the result of I/O without stopping the thread (the thread is given other work to do until the I/O is complete).

**[jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/learn/)** is a Java-first product for writing and executing SQL in a typesafe way, but does not itself make explicit use of Kotlin coroutines.

Can jOOQ be called from a Kotlin co-routine scope to get the nice-to-write and thread-is-productive-even-during-IO benefits?

```
suspend fun myQuery() {
  return dsl.select()
  // .etc()
  .fetch()  // <- could this be a 'suspend' call?
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A: Yes.

**BECAUSE**
`org.jooq.ResultQuery<R extends Record>` has a [`@NotNull CompletionStage<Result<R>> fetchAsync()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchAsync())` method which hooks into Java's (JDK 8+) machinery for 'futures'.

**AND**
`kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8` provides a [bunch of extension methods](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8/src/future/Future.kt) for adapting between Kotlin suspending functions and JDK 8+ futures.

**THEREFORE** we can do:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.future.await
...
suspend fun myQuery() {
  return dsl.select()
  //.etc()
  .fetchAsync()
  .await()    // <- IS  a suspending call !!!
}
```

It should be noted that there are a bunch of overloaded `fetchX()` methods on `ResultQuery` which provide lots of utility to synchronous calls, but they are not similarly overloaded for `fetchAsync()`.  That's where the Kotlin programmer may wish to be familiar with the Java futures machinery: any sort of manipulation can be accomplished asynchronously using the [`thenApply {}` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html) on `CompletionStage<T>`.  For example, mapping the results:

```
suspend fun myQuery() {
  return dsl.select()
  //.etc()
  .fetchAsync()
  .thenApply { it.map(mapping(::Film)) }  // <- done as part of the 'suspend'
  .await()
}
```

although it should be fine to do it after the suspend:

```
suspend fun myQuery() {
  val records = dsl.select()
  //.etc()
  .fetchAsync()
  .await()

  return records.map(mapping(::Film))
}
```

Comment: As mentioned on your previous question, the `CompletionStage` will hopefully be [non-blocking in the near future, if supplied with an R2DBC connection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68911636/521799)

Comment: @LukasEder Yes, though there are still advantages to be had (ie. minimal external design-forces distorting the 'shape of code') from the Kotlin side even though r2dbc is not *yet* in use under the covers for the actual non-blocking.  Anyone who uses JDBC has the blocking behaviour, so it's not like anything is *lost* by using jOOQ.  It's only people who are willing to distort their code-shape into the reactive style, and to live with the immaturity of r2dbc, who are any 'better off'.  But with jOOQ, I can patiently wait for those gains while writing my app the way it *should be*.

Comment: @DavidBullock do you have any guidance on the optimal way to configure the `executorProvider` thread pool for jooq when using this API in JDBC blocking mode? For reference I'm using ktor as my server (coroutine-based), so I don't have an existing thread pool configured for blocking DB operations.

Answer (score 2):

JOOQ added R2dbc support, the `ResultQuery` is a ReactiveStreams `Publisher`.

Currently the simplest approach is using Reactor Kotlin extension to convert the Reactor APIs to Kotlin Coroutines APIs.

```kotlin
  Flux.from(
     ctx.select()
     ...//etc
     ...// do not call fetch
  ) 
  .asFlow()
```

**Update**: Jooq guys cancelled [the PR of Kotlin Coroutines on DslContext](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9335#issuecomment-1057827831), so now you have to use `kotlinx-coroutines-ractor` as above.

<del>When switching to 3.17 or later, use `fetchAwait` directly. There is a series of `xxxAwait` added.</del>

```
ctx.select()
     ...//etc
     .fetchAwait()
```

<del>but I did not find direct support for Kotlin Coroutines,**Jooq 3.17 ships official Koltin Coroutines support in `jooq-kotlin` module**.</del>

Comment: The remark about the cancellation of this feature has been outdated, in the meantime. Given how simple it was, eventually, a `jooq-kotlin-coroutines` extension module has been added: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/kotlin-sql-building/kotlin-coroutines/